# Styling a table generated with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have some javascript that parses a csv file and puts the content onto a table.

I am generating the table with a pretty generic function that goes through a 2D array and build an html string. 
I then do

```
document.getElementById("StringTable").innerHTML = result;
```

My table generates just fine and works great for what I need.

I wanted to apply some CSS styling just to have it a bit nicer to look at but I can't seem to get my css file to have any effect on the table.

I'm thinking its because the table is generated after the css is loaded but I'm not sure how to get around this. What can I do?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="StrRecTable">


    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function makeTableHTML(array) {
    var result = "<table border=2, width=1000px>";
    result += "<thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>D_1</th><th>D_2</th><th>D_3</th><th>D_4</th><th>D_5</th><th>D_6</th></thead><tbody>";
    // Create header row. Better way to do this?
    //for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var i = array.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
        result += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            result += "<td>"+array[i][j]+"</td>";   
        }   
        result += "</tr>";
    }   
    result += "</tbody></table>";
    document.getElementById("StrRecTable").innerHTML = result;
}
```

CSS: (this was automatically generated from some website. I just wanted to play around with it.

```
body {background-color:#888888;}

.StrRecTable {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border:1px solid #125b07;

-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
border-bottom-left-radius:25px;

-moz-border-radius-bottomright:25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
border-bottom-right-radius:25px;

-moz-border-radius-topright:25px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:25px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;

-moz-border-radius-topleft:25px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:25px;
border-top-left-radius:25px;
}.StrRecTable table{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0px;padding:0px;
}.StrRecTable tr:last-child td:last-child {
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
}
.StrRecTable table tr:first-child td:first-child {
-moz-border-radius-topleft:25px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:25px;
border-top-left-radius:25px;
}
.StrRecTable table tr:first-child td:last-child {
-moz-border-radius-topright:25px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:25px;
border-top-right-radius:25px;
}.StrRecTable tr:last-child td:first-child{
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:25px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
}.StrRecTable tr:hover td{

}
.StrRecTable tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#7f7f7f; }
.StrRecTable tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#333333; }.StrRecTable td{
vertical-align:middle;


border:1px solid #125b07;
border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
text-align:left;
padding:5px;
font-size:10px;
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:normal;
color:#ffffff;
}.StrRecTable tr:last-child td{
border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}.StrRecTable tr td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}.StrRecTable tr:last-child td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.StrRecTable tr:first-child td{
    background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fbf00 5%, #5fbf00 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5fbf00), color-stop(1, #5fbf00) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #5fbf00 5%, #5fbf00 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#5fbf00", endColorstr="#5fbf00");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#5fbf00,5fbf00);

background-color:#5fbf00;
border:0px solid #125b07;
text-align:center;
border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
font-size:12px;
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ffffff;
}
.StrRecTable tr:first-child:hover td{
background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #5fbf00 5%, #5fbf00 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #5fbf00), color-stop(1, #5fbf00) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #5fbf00 5%, #5fbf00 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#5fbf00", endColorstr="#5fbf00");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#5fbf00,5fbf00);

background-color:#5fbf00;
}
.StrRecTable tr:first-child td:first-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.StrRecTable tr:first-child td:last-child{
border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
}
```

edited to add HTML/CSS

Comment: Post your CSS code and your HTML.

Comment: 'I'm thinking its because the table is generated after the css is loaded' - there should be no issue with that. Check your CSS, there is the problem

Comment: It doesn't matter when the css is loaded. Otherwise everything you receive by ajax would looking pretty ugly ;-)

Comment: You can add classes with jquery to your table-elements. Then you can style this classes with your stylesheet then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS uses a class for **.StrRecTable** but your JavaScript references it by id

```
document.getElementById("StrRecTable").innerHTML = result;
```

Adding a class to the div will work, or referencing the ID in the CSS:

```
<body>
    <div id="StrRecTable" class="StrRecTable">


    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7Y5/2/) of it working with the CSS updated to reference the ID of the holder DIV.

Comment: Thanks! I am very new to web languages so I sometimes make dumb mistakes! Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

- Your HTML includes a div with the `id` of StrRecTable.
- Your CSS targets an element with the `class` of StrRecTable

  1. `.someText` will target elements with the `class` of 'someText'
  2. `#someText` will target the element with the `id` of 'someText'

Simples!

Comment: Thanks for helping a noobie out! I got it sorted now